# how do i properly start a javafx animation using timeline?

Tags: animation, javafx, timeline

I am trying to use code gathered off of this website to make an application that bounces circles around. when i click now - it creates a circle that just seems to vibrate in place and does not bounce off of the borders.

HERE IS THE CODE HAT SOLLVED MY ISSUE THANKS GUYS

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPane;
@FXML
private Label ballCountLabel;

public int ballCount = 0;
public int mouseClick = 0;

Circle[] balls = new Circle[1000];

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pane, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(pane, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(pane, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(pane, 0.0);
}

@FXML
private void mouseAddBall(MouseEvent event) throws Exception {

    balls[mouseClick] = new Circle(15, Color.BLANCHEDALMOND);
    balls[mouseClick].relocate(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
    pane.getChildren().add(balls[mouseClick]);
    ballCount++;
    ballCountLabel.setText("Ball Count: " + ballCount);
    addBallMovement(balls[mouseClick]);
    mouseClick++;
}
public void addBallMovement(Circle b){

    final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        double deltaX = 3;
        double deltaY = 3;

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            b.setLayoutX(b.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
            b.setLayoutY(b.getLayoutY() + deltaY);

            final Bounds bounds = pane.getBoundsInParent();

            final boolean atRightBorder = b.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - b.getRadius());
            final boolean atLeftBorder = b.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + b.getRadius());
            final boolean atBottomBorder = b.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - b.getRadius());
            final boolean atTopBorder = b.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + b.getRadius());

            if (atRightBorder || atLeftBorder) {
                deltaX *= -1;
            }
            if (atBottomBorder || atTopBorder) {
                deltaY *= -1;
            }
        }
    }));
    loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    loop.play();
```

Comment: please post the stack trace of your `Exception` or the error message the compiler spits out. In the case of an `Exception` also tell us which part of your code threw it

Comment: Post your `Ball` class also.

Comment: at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)

Comment: Post the complete stack trace in the actual question, not in comments

Comment: You don't uncheck this answer as correct and change the question. You should have created a new question with your new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `Ball` to `Circle` to test your code. You are changing to the next ball in the `balls` array before you add movement to the current ball. This is probably giving you a `NullPointerException`.

Change

```
balls[mouseClick] = new Circle(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY(), 
Math.random() * 20);
pane.getChildren().add(balls[mouseClick]);
mouseClick++;
ballCount++;
ballCountLabel.setText("Ball Count: " + ballCount);
addBallMovement(balls[mouseClick]);  //<--You want to move the current ball. This code needs to be before mouseClick++
```

To:

```
balls[mouseClick] = new Circle(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY(), 
Math.random() * 20);
pane.getChildren().add(balls[mouseClick]);
addBallMovement(balls[mouseClick]);
mouseClick++;
ballCount++;
ballCountLabel.setText("Ball Count: " + ballCount);
```

Comment: haha yes! i did this, but now when i run the program i get vibrating balls!

Comment: This answer solved your question. Accept it and then try to tackle your new problem. After putting in a lot of effort on your new problem, ask a new question.